# Local Realm dbs for multiple users

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to implement a user based realm db. So each time a new users registers, a Realm file is created with his UID (from Firebase), or if exists, accesses that Realm.
To do that i created a singletone for the Realm calls and setting the Realm Configuration.

My issue now is that, every time i switch the users, the realm path changes (i'm printing after users logged in), but the Results reading are the same, as the users didn't change, or the realm did not switch. To be more clear, the queries results are giving same data.

If i open the actual Realms, the data is different.

I'm seeing this behavior in my tableView, just by loading data.

What am i doing wrong?

RealmServices:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import Firebase


class RealmServices {
    
    private init() {}
    static let shared = RealmServices()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    var realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration.init(
                            fileURL: Realm.Configuration().fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).realm")))
    
   
    
    
    func create<T:Object> (_ object: T) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(object)
            }
        } catch {
            post(error)
        }
    }
    
    func update <T: Object>(_ object: T, with dictionary: [String : Any?]) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                for (key,value) in dictionary {
                    object.setValue(value, forKey: key)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            post (error)
        }
    }
    
    func delete<T:Object> (_ object: T) {
        do {
            try realm.write{
                realm.delete(object)
            }
        } catch {
            post (error)
        }
    }
    
    func post (_ error: Error) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("RealmError"), object: error)
    }
    
    func observeRealmErrors (in vc: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (Error?)-> Void) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("RealmError"), object: nil, queue: nil) { (Notification) in
            completion(Notification.object as? Error)
        }
    }
    
    func stopObservingError (in vc: UIViewController){
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(vc, name: NSNotification.Name("RealmError"), object: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If you are using a singleton, and switch users without restarting the app, then your singleton will always refer to the same realm. A singleton for multiple users sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: But the URL changes for the singletone as soon as new user is logged in, isn't it ?

Comment: No, you need to update the realm property with the appropriate configuration every time a new user logs in

Comment: If you're strictly using Realm on a local device, the singleton pattern is fine - although it has its downsides. However, how you're working with Firebase users may be problematic. What process are you using to authenticate a user? How are they *unauthenticated* when 'switching' users? Also, it may be a good idea to update your code to reflect what's shown in the Guide [Configuring a local realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/open-a-realm#open-a-local--non-synced--realm) as I don't see you're populating it with the default configuration

Comment: @RobertCrabtree I think the intention here is that when a user is authenticated and attempts to read data from realm, the appropriate configuration is used based on their firebase uid. In other words if *user_a* is logged in, when they read realm it's reading realm at the realm path of */appname/user_a.realm*. Each time Realm is read, the singleton sets the path to their uid so the singleton pattern will work for this case.

Comment: Jay, the Firebase authentification is standard, nothing fancy, and like you said by logic it should change the realm reading file based on the authentificated user. As soon as user logs out, a sign in view displays and a new user/or existing user is signing in. I lost two days figuring out why this doesn't work. I will just use the default path and make a User object and query them. If someone will figure it out maybe it will be helpful to share.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is going on (I could be totally off but let me give it a shot)

Your RealmServices is a singleton and initialized only once. It's not a subclass where each time one is created, it's initialized

So any var's are set up and populated on first run - the `realm` property is not going to re-initialize each time it's accessed. For example, take this singleton

```
final class MySingleton {
    private init() {}
    var someUuid = UUID().uuidString
    static let sharedInstance = MySingleton()
}
```

as you can see, someUuId is a 'randomly' generated uuid. If you access that property twice, it presents the same value, there's nothing to force an update.

```
print(MySingleton.sharedInstance.someUuid)
print(MySingleton.sharedInstance.someUuid)
```

results in

```
EBE131DE-B574-4CE1-8D74-E680D80A577B
EBE131DE-B574-4CE1-8D74-E680D80A577B
```

So, the solution is to set the users uid property in your question to a different value each time you want it changed. Here's a quick example

```
final class RealmService {
    
    private init() {}
    
    var uid: String!
    var usersRealm: Realm! {
        let path = Realm.Configuration().fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("\(uid!).realm")
        let realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration.init(fileURL: path))
        return realm
    }

    static let sharedInstance = RealmService()
}
```

and here's how it's called; in this example we write item0 to user0's realm and item1 to user1's realm:

```
RealmService.sharedInstance.uid = "uid_0"
let user0Realm = RealmService.sharedInstance.usersRealm!

let item0 = ItemClass(name: "item 0")

try! user0Realm.write {
    user0Realm.add(item0)
}

RealmService.sharedInstance.uid = "uid_1"
let user1Realm = RealmService.sharedInstance.usersRealm!

let item1 = ItemClass(name: "item 1")

try! user1Realm.write {
    user1Realm.add(item1)
}
```

the result is a realm being created for each user with item0 in user0's realm and item1 being in user1's realm

[image]

Comment: I will try your version tomorrow, the thing is that in my case it was also creating the files, but it was not loading the right file after first login. The second logged in user was seeing same data ( and table.reloads and thing like this are considered). It may be that it is initialized and i need to “close it” or “reinitialize” it. I will come with an update.

Comment: @Radu Cool. This was just guesswork on my part - it may have something to do with how the users are being logged in/out of firebase as well. Keep me posted.